# Kannada language support in xwiki

Tags: localization, xwiki, kannada

I am working on a project where I create pages in the kannada language which will be edited by others. I am planning to use the XWiki platform. Does XWiki provide Kannada editing support?
If not, what other wiki platform can I use?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see Kannada characters are part of UTF8 so there should be no issue with XWiki. I just copy pasted some text in a wiki to test it and here is what it looks like: http://tuska.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Test/%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1

There is no XWiki translation in Kannada language yet but you can propose one if you like, see http://l10n.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/L10N/AddALanguage for more details.

Comment: Thank you..Yes.. I too tried pasting some text..It works but,i am working on a project where i want the users of the wiki to edit and correct the mistakes in kannada document..For that i need built in editing kannada..Is there any wiki software that provides support for this?? thank you..